# How to make multi-level list in HTML?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-lists

I am parsing a XML document and creating a HTML list using it. I have encountered a situation where i need to make a multi-level list out of the XML data. For example:

```
1. One
2. Two
  2.1. Three
  2.2. Four
    2.2.1. Five
    2.2.2. Six
  2.3. Seven
3. Eight
```

Is it possible to create such a structure in HTML preferably using `<ul>-<li>s`? I have encountered a few solutions where it is suggested to use `counter-incretemnt, counter-reset` in CSS but the trouble is that sort of solution is not viable for my situations due to the XML's structure and also coz it would be extremely difficult to write it using XSLT.

Can anyone suggest me a solution to this problem?

Note: There is no limit to the levels of the lists!

Thnx in advance!!

EDIT: Adding the sample XML for the above desired HTML list:

```
<ele lvl="0">
  One
</ele>
<ele lvl="0">
  Two
</ele>
<ele lvl="1">
  Three
</ele>
<ele lvl="1">
  Four
</ele>
<ele lvl="2">
  Five
</ele>
<ele lvl="2">
  Six
</ele>
<ele lvl="1">
  Seven
</ele>
<ele lvl="0">
  Eight
<ele>
```

Comment: You can, but you will still need to style it using CSS counters. You don't have to style the XML with CSS.

Comment: *"not viable for my situations due to the XML's structure"* What does *that* have to do with it? *"and also coz it would be extremely difficult to write it using XSLT."* - No, it wouldn't.

Comment: What is the structure of your input XML?

Comment: @Tomalak added a sample XML, can you now suggest a way to create the desired HTML list?

Comment: If my solution solves your problem it would be nice if you gave some sort of feedback.

Comment: @Tomalak sorry for the late feedback, i hadn't got around to try it yet coz of a crisis at work... but in all likeliness it seems it will do the job... thnx! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This XSLT stylesheet outputs your list as correctly nested HTML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <!-- this key indexes <ele> by their level -->
  <xsl:key name="kLevel" match="ele" use="@lvl" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Nested List</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:call-template name="list">
          <xsl:with-param name="elems" select="key('kLevel', '0')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- this makes a new list from a set of <ele> -->
  <xsl:template name="list">
    <xsl:param name="elems" />

    <ol>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$elems" />
    </ol>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- this makes a list item and, optionally, a sub-list -->
  <xsl:template match="ele">
    <xsl:variable name="myLevel" select="@lvl" />
    <xsl:variable name="myChildren" select="key('kLevel', $myLevel + 1)[
      generate-id(preceding-sibling::ele[@lvl = $myLevel][1])
      =
      generate-id(current())
    ]" />

    <li>
      <span><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
      <xsl:if test="$myChildren">
        <xsl:call-template name="list">
          <xsl:with-param name="elems" select="$myChildren" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The meaning of

```
key('kLevel', $myLevel + 1)[
  generate-id(preceding-sibling::ele[@lvl = $myLevel][1])
  =
  generate-id(current())
]
```

is *"all `<ele>` with a level one step down"* (`key('kLevel', $myLevel + 1)`, i.e. all *potential* children of the current node) *"where the ID of the immediately preceding `<ele>`  having the current level (`generate-id(preceding-sibling::ele[@lvl = $myLevel][1])`)"*, i.e. the logical parent of each potential child) *"equals the ID of the current node"* (`= generate-id(current())`).

In essence this matches all potential children of a node against all their potential parents, returning the "inner join" (if you will) - the set of nodes that *actually are* children of the current node.

Applied to your input:

```
<elems>
  <ele lvl="0">One</ele>
  <ele lvl="0">Two</ele>
  <ele lvl="1">Three</ele>
  <ele lvl="1">Four</ele>
  <ele lvl="2">Five</ele>
  <ele lvl="2">Six</ele>
  <ele lvl="1">Seven</ele>
  <ele lvl="0">Eight</ele>
</elems>
```

This returns

```
<ol>
  <li><span>One</span></li>
  <li>
    <span>Two</span>
    <ol>
      <li><span>Three</span></li>
      <li>
        <span>Four</span>
        <ol>
          <li><span>Five</span></li>
          <li><span>Six</span></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li><span>Seven</span></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><span>Eight</span></li>
</ol>
```

Now when you apply [CSS outline numbering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters),

```
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") ". ";
}
```

you get the wanted result

```
1. One
2. Two
   2.1. Three
   2.2. Four
        2.2.1. Five
        2.2.2. Six
   2.3. Seven
3. Eight
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `<ul>` tags and attach them different classes (according to level)

for example

```
<ul class="treeLevel1">
 <li>root</li>
 <ul class="treeLevel2">
  <li>home</li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

after that in attach different margin to different classes (treeLevel1, treeLevel2, ...) in css

```
.treeLevel1 {
    margin-left: 0.10em;
}
.treeLevel2 {
    margin-left: 0.40em;
}
```

Comment: yes but that wouldn't change the numbering of the list.. if you will notice, i need 2.1., 2.1.1.,.. kind of numbering...

Comment: i don't see the problem, `<ul class="2.1"><ul class="2.1.1"><li>foo</li></ul></ul>`

Comment: How will that change the numbering of the list to the desired outputs? You are only suggesting the way to handle indentations of the list, that is not an issue. What I want is a way to change the numbering of the list...